# Can not set UITableViewDataSouce and UITableViewDelegate to UIViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift, xcode6

When I try to set the delegate and datasource to a **UIViewController**, all functions that run fine in **UITableViewController** are detected as errors.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10
}
```

The error is

```
FirstViewController.swift:11:1: Type 'FirstViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource':

UIKit.UITableViewDataSource:2:48: Protocol requires function      'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' with type '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
FirstViewController.swift:29:10: Candidate has non-matching type '(UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
UIKit.UITableViewDataSource:3:48: Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' with type '(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell'
FirstViewController.swift:29:10: Candidate has non-matching type '(UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int'
```

This is Xcode 6 (not a beta version). Is table view delegation no longer supported inside **UIViewController**?

(The same code is working in Xcode 6, Beta 5, but not in the Xcode 6 GM.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using [implicitly unwrapped optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334) (`UITableView!`). But this code no longer uses optionals.

The method signatures now look like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Yes silly me, i found my answer at http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift,...
Damn apple they change this vital point without teling us. thank Aaron, i accept your answer

Comment: @DeckyFx I think they did tell us in the release notes :)

Comment: LOL may be, so i may missed this, they should make this change notes more noticeable

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 6, to override delegation function in `UIViewController`, use this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just different a few second ^_^, thanks anyway Ahmad